# Obtaining operations execution info for Redis Cache and App Service in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-redis-cache, azure-storage-account

I have a storage account in Azure for which I have enabled diagnostic monitoring of Blob and Table services logs. Looking at these logs gives me information about the operations executed on the storage account - like ListBlobs, GetBlobs and whether these operations succeeded or not.

Can similar information be obtained for Redis Cache and App Service? If yes, how do I find the log entries?

Comment: You're asking for Cloud Service stats - what, exactly, are you looking for? Cloud Services have web and worker role instances.

Comment: @ David...I just edited the question. Please have another look. I wanted the data for app service and Redis cache